# Tomcat 8.5.x freezes

Tags: apache, loading, tomcat8, freeze

I use Tomcat 8.5.x zip version (no GUI) and when I proceed a huge amount of requests from my load balancing Apache Server everything works fine. The problem occurs when I stop doing anything (stop sending requests) for like 5-10-15+ minutes, the moment when I want to log-in or do something, my site won't load, Tomcat won't accept the request and when I right-click on Tomcat, it unfreezes and the requests are proceeded. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Running Tomcat as service and increasing heap size did the work.